# What prerequisites are there to Learning Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have knowledge of HTML, CSS, and Javascript, Do I need any previous knowledge of a server side language such as PHP to get started with and fully grasp Node.js?

What are some of your opinions on whether it is better to start learning node.js
since I already have experience with Javascript or should I learn a server side 
language before hand?

Comment: I'd say you need to at least understand the server-client model and how the HTTP protocol works. that should be enough to get you started if you already know JS.

Comment: JavaScript *is* a server side language when you run node on a server.

Comment: No reason to mess up your brain learning PHP.

Comment: The only prerequiste to learning new languages or frameworks is knowing how to google.

Comment: There is no need to learn PHP in advance, because it's very different from Node JS. But if you want to earn money soon, i would recommend to learn PHP. It's more common than Node JS - at least at the moment (and probably the next years). You're really need to get good in Node JS to find someone who will hire you.

Comment: @JacobKrall PHP is not that bad. It teaches you self control to avoid doing spaghetti-code.

Comment: It's important that you don't pigeonhole node.js into just another web language. Just because you can serve a web page with it does not mean that's all it can do. In fact, some of its best features have little (or nothing) to do with websites at all. And for chrissake, don't learn PHP beforehand (or ever); it's completely dissimilar to node.

Comment: You don't even need to know much of Javascript. The fundamentals of Javascript would take you through Node JS. With time you would be versed in Javascript while learning Node JS.